# Javascript Regex to replace not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

Test string is:

```
hello hello hello

<span class="self-reference">Tom</span> I don't know <span class="self-reference">Tom</span> I don't think.
```

I wish to to come out as:

```
hello hello hello

@Tom I don't know @Tom I don't think.
```

I use this regex:

```
comment = comment.replace(/\<span class="self-reference"\>(.*)\<\/span\>/gi,"@$1");
```

But it outputs:

```
hello hello hello

@Tom</span> I don't know <span class="self-reference">Tom I don't think.
```

Can anyone tell me how to modify this so it works as expected?

Comment: Obligatory.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use non-greedy regex matching:

```
comment = comment.replace(/\<span class="self-reference"\>(.*?)\<\/span\>/gi,"@$1");
```

Without the `?` I added, your regex (.*) will match the whole string up to the last `</span>` it founds in your string. Using non-greedy operator `*?` you make the match stop as soon as a match is found.

> Lazy quantification
>
> The standard quantifiers in regular expressions are greedy, meaning they match as much as they can.

([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression))

Comment: Although it's the exact opposite of greedy :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
comment = comment.replace(/\<span class="self-reference"\>([^<]+)\<\/span\>/gi,"@$1");
```

`([^<]+)` captures all chars until `<` is found